# 4-20 mA current loop transmitter

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet

[image]
Circuit reference from [Analog Devices](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/D61_EN-Convert.pdf)

The above circuit produces the correct output in simulations (Proteus and Altium).

When the circuit is built on the board, the first stage produces the correct output, but the second-stage op-amp can't equalize the inputs.

In a test: non-inverting input 20.3 V, inverting input 15.7 V, op-amp output 0.1 V (th is 2.1).

Also used:

- ISP25DP06NMXTSA1 P-channel MOSFET (Vgs threshold 2.1 V, Rds(on) 250 mΩ).
- 220 Ω for R3 and 100 Ω for R6 (they are current sense resistors - 1 W).
- LT1491A op-amp (4-ch).

What is the reason why the second-stage op-amp can't produce the correct output?

Comment: What output load did you have?

Comment: 250Ω load resistance

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bad design from Analog Devices.

The [IRF9Z245](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91090/91090.pdf) MOSFET that drives the output has a maximum gate-source voltage rating of +/- 20 volts. This is the crucial thing to note. Yet, if you don't have a proper load connected, the op-amp output will try and force the gate-source voltage to be -24 volts and that may damage the MOSFET. It's a bad design at the very least as far as I can tell.

The MOSFET you used (ISP25DP06NMXTSA1) also has a 20 volt maximum gate-source voltage by the way. Normally, you would use a zener diode to protect the gate-source region. So, if at any moment in time you ran the circuit without a load you could have fried the MOSFET.

Comment: i checked the mosfet, it seems working. also almost all tests done while load is connected. i can check zener diode and high Vgs scale mosfet

Comment: It's still a bad design and, that is an important observation.

Comment: Confirmed for Zener diode necessary when open load.

Comment: checked with DMP3056L-7 p-ch mosfet and 25V zener diode, but its still same. first stage is working well. but second stage opamp couldnt equalize inputs.

Comment: when i give 3V input the M1 Vgs=-200mV

Comment: Maybe you have a layout problem or you have misconnected a device in your circuit.

Comment: also check connection and layout problem always. but i guess its about mosfet. i have two tools for simulation, Altium and Proteus. 3V input, proteus giving Vgs=18V, altium giving Vgs=-25V. altium might be correct. because i measured negative voltage on Vgs, according to altium i need more then 24V (and also negative voltage) for second stage can work as it must be. i think its not possible for an opamp with 0 lower limit and 24v upper limit. Im i right?

Comment: It'll work with the LT1490 because it can drive the output high enough to deactivate the MOSFET.